# why the language is change to English in language bar in c#

Tags: c#

When I run any project in Visual Studio 2010 the language gets automatically changed to English in language bar of win 7. And when I use the code

`Message Box.Show(Thread.Current Thread.Current Culture.Name);`

in button event handler. If i select English language or Arabic or any think in the language bar Message Box.Show is print only English

any one help me please

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Resource file for each language, e.g., one for English, another one for Arabic and so on.

You can get more information about .NET Localization from below links:

- [.NET Localization, Part 1: Resource Managers](http://www.ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/09/30/manager.html)
- [.NET Localization, Part 2: Creating Satellite Assemblies](http://www.ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/10/14/local2.htm)
- [.NET Localization, Part 3: Localizing Text](http://www.ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/10/21/localpt3.htm)
- [.NET Localization, Part 4: Localizing Units](http://www.ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/10/28/intlpart4.html)

Comment: i need a simple example for change application language when selecting another language in language bar